# Find "*" using regular expression in Libre Office

Tags: regex, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I want to find * character using regular expression because I have to replace it with \n*. Basically I want to add a line before all the * present in the document.

However when I tried to find it with Regular expression checked, it showed no result, after turning off regular expression it can find the character but I can't add a manual line before every * in one go. And the document is like 2K pages long so doing it again and again one by one is not really an option for me. So how do I go about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a backslash to make it literal.

Find: `\*`
Replace: `\n*`

Documentation is at: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer#Special_characters

Comment: Thanks that helped.
Can you please tell me how do I remove a paragraph break. You see After every ":" there is paragraph break. When I search using :$ it searches for it, but no matter with what I replace, the para break will not go.
Or should I create a new question for this ? I am still learning this regular expression thing, and with new document to make into epub, I get into more trouble and learn something new.

Comment: That should be a separate question.